# jQuery .append() Crashing browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, backbone.js

I'm using backbone and made one slight(seemingly irrelevant to performance) change to my code. I only changed the destination in which my views were getting appended to.

**Working render function**

```
render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model));
    $('.wide-container').append(this.el);
}
```

**Not working render function (crashes browser)**

```
render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model));
    $('.another-container ul').append(this.el);
}
```

Each this.el is an `<li>` tag if that is of use.

Any help or insight is much appreciated.

Comment: Are `this.$el` and `this.el` different objects?

Comment: try to alert or console each of 'this. ' and check if you are getting right value

Comment: They are essentially the same object, `this.$el` just being the `$(this.el)`

Comment: @user2181397 I've done just that and it's the correct view that shows up in the console

Comment: are there a LOT of `.another-container ul`s?

Comment: Does `this.el` happen to contain a `<ul>`?

Comment: @iam-decoder There's only one

Comment: @Stryner Wow, just found the designer put in a `ul` in the template. I changed that and it worked! Does appending more `ul`'s to a `ul` make the performance crash? Thank you!

Comment: @JustinHathaway `$('.another-container ul')` will get all the `<ul>`'s inside the class. So if you're appending multiple items, it will find more `<ul>`'s each time. If the `this.el` is an element, it will eventually be appended to the last `<ul>` it finds. I doubt that would crash the browser, unless you're appending a *ton* of elements. If `this.el` is a string, then it will append that string to *every* `<ul>`. That would most likely crash the browser.

Comment: @Stryner Ah, that makes complete sense. Thank you so much!